# get xml attribute of button android java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Please help I have the a number of buttons with text and images in a layout in my activity_main.xml file.

```
<Button
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ring"
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:text="pic1" />
```

Each of the other buttons have a different @drawable resource, id and text.

Question: How would I programmatically loop through each of the buttons in MainActivity.java and obtain the value of the @drawableTop attribute, so in the above case - ring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> Drawable[] getCompoundDrawables ()
>
> Returns drawables for the left, top, right, and bottom borders.

So

```
button.getCompoundDrawables()[1];
```

will return drawable for top.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to know how many children have the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout that you are using. Then, create a loop to get each child. Finally, validate the type of the view and get the drawable top.

```
LinearLayout layout = setupLayout();
int count = layout.getChildCount();
View view = null;
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    view = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof Button) {
       Button myButton = (Button) view;
       Drawable drawableTop = myButton.getCompoundDrawables()[1];
       //YOUR CODE
    }
}
```